# Python: Call my script from command line using another function

Tags: python-3.x, input, cmd, command-line-arguments, user-input

I have a function called MyScript() that I have defined in a file called MyScript.py. MyScript takes several arguments that I would like to prompt the user in the command line to enter. So I wrote a separate function RunMyScript() defined in RunMyScript.py to first run in the command line to gather the arguments:

```
def RunMyScript():
  import os
  dir1 = input('Enter the Directory1 file path: ')
  dir2 = input('Enter the Directory2 file path: ')
  dir3 = input('Enter the Directory3 file path: ' )
  flag = input('Flag? (Y/N): ')

os.chdir = dir1
from MyScript import MyScript
MyScript(dir2,dir3,flag)
```

And then generically the MyScript function begins:

```
def MyScript(dir2,dir3,flag="N"):
    import os

    os.chdir(dir2)
    if flag=="Y":
    DoSomething
    wb.save(dir3)
```

When I try to run RunMyScript in the command line I get the error "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable. I suspect it has something to do with how it interprets the flag input Y or N, but I'm not positive.

I am new to Python and the site so please pardon me if the question is not phrased properly, I will provide more detail as needed, and I have searched the site for similar questions but it's not clear that I'm having the same problem as others in the past.

Thank you.

Comment: What line is the error occurring on?  What are the contents of the line?

Comment: Have you tried add single quotes to the input?

Comment: After making the change @Kevin suggested below, I've now narrowed it down to the Flag arg and I think how it's being passed through to MyScript. Think because the user input from RunMyScript "Y" or "N" is being interpreted as a string, it fails when trying to call in MyScript. So I need to convert to a variable. Will post answer if that works

Comment: My interim solution feels cheap but basically I just added lines to RunMyScript to say 'if Flag = N Flag =1 elif Flag = Y Flag = 2' and then passed it through to MyScript as an int not a str. Leaving the post open though as others may have better answers that could be useful to others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MyScript function you call `os.chdir(dir2)` but `os.chdir` is a string and it's not callable. Try `os.chdir = dir2` instead.

EDIT : It's the opposite... I'm so confused.

But now, didn't you have a scope issue ? When I copy-paste your code, it doesn't work because `os.chdir(dir1)` isn't in the same scope that `import os`.

I suggest you to move all the `import` to the top of script and change `input` in `raw_input` to a best support of string input.

Try to change your code like that :

```
import os
import MyScript

def RunMyScript():
    dir1 = raw_input('Enter the Directory1 file path: ')
    dir2 = raw_input('Enter the Directory2 file path: ')
    dir3 = raw_input('Enter the Directory3 file path: ' )
    flag = raw_input('Flag? (Y/N): ')

    os.chdir(dir1)
    MyScript(dir2, dir3, flag)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    RunMyScript()
```

and for MyScript :

```
import os 

def MyScript(dir2, dir3, flag = "N"):
    os.chdir(dir2)

    if flag == "Y":
        #Do Something

    wb.save(dir3)
```

I hope that solve your problem.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html), it `os.chdir()` is certainly a function.

Comment: That was definitely part of the issue as @Kevin raised above, should be:
    os.chdir(dir1) 
in RunMyScript silly since I did it right the second time

Comment: @BJBeans I changed my answer. Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you! What is the thought behind the 
    if __name__ == '__main__':
I've been reading about it elsewhere here but unsure how it applies in my specific case

Comment: In your case, if the script is the main script (not an import) `RunMyScript ()` is automatically called. So if you import your script in an other script `RunMyScript ()` is not automatically called. 
You can read the condition like "if this script is the main script do this.."

Comment: Got it thank you that's a clear definition, appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you are attempting to do but I would think your problem has to do with the line :

```
os.chdir = dir1
```

You are changing os.chdir to a string.  To properly change the directory you should use:

```
os.chdir(dir1)
```

Comment: This is part of it thank you. To your broader point - I'm attempting to use the Run function to give the user an easier/prompted way to assign the needed directory arguments for MyScript (specific to their environment) in the command line, before MyScript executes. Thought being I can do some error handling up front as well - so if they enter the directory wrong. 

There may be a better overall way to do that, for instance I've seen some references to the "sys" module searching this site, but wasn't sure if it applied.